# Update a specific column with a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns: username, password and ID.Every password and username have a specific ID. Table name is "Account" for example.

I want to update a password with a specific ID. I have tried:

```
 UPDATE Account SET password = "newPassword"
                        where id = 1
```

However, it does not work. It will complain that "newPassword" is not a valid column name. I try my queries in SQL management studio.

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: you query seems correct. Do you run it from code-program or an editor? Do you get any errors? However keep in mind that password is a reserved keyword. Is it actually your column name?

Comment: I get error when I write password = "newPassword" as it will complain "newPassword" is not a valid column name.

Comment: You should be using single quotes for string literals in MySQL, but AFAIK double quotes might work as well.

Comment: define *"does not work"*. Is the password changed but you are unable to connect wih the new one ?

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL standard says that strings needs to be single qouted not double qouted , MySQL does not care for string values to be single qouted or double qouted... if this errors **1) You are not using MySQL** 2) Not selected on working database -> `USE` 3) invalid columns .... long list..

Comment: Thank you. It was the double quotes that made it not work.

Comment: ANSI SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. column names with odd characters (like `"newPassword"`.) MySQL on the other hand uses back-ticks for delimited identifiers. Are you really sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: *"I try my queries in SQL management studio"* This is for **MS SQL Server**, not MySQL. Please use correct tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes for string literals in MS SQL Server:

```
UPDATE Account
SET password = 'newPassword'
WHERE id = 1;
```

Double quotes in SQL are generally reserved for database objects, such as table and column names (sometimes called identifiers).  Your current update is attempting to assign the `password` column to a column named `newPassword`.  This column doesn't exist, hence you are getting an error.

Comment: He's using SQL Management Studio, though.